# Ruby daemons on Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

I'm trying to execute a ruby daemon *framework-less* app on Heroku, but it crash after trying to execute the worker:

```
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake twitter:start`
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

The app basically collects data, through a bunch of APIs, and saves it on a remote MongoHQ instance.

The rake tasks are:

```
dir_path = File.expand_path('../', __FILE__)

namespace :twitter do
  desc 'Start Twitter daemon'
  task :start do
    exec "#{dir_path}/bin/autana start"
  end

  ...
end
```

The Procfile is very simple: `worker: bundle exec rake twitter:start`

The code that executes the daemon is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'daemons'
require File.expand_path('../../lib/autana', __FILE__)

Daemons.run_proc('autana', multiple: true, no_pidfiles: true) do
  client = Autana::Client::Twitter.new
  client.collect
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you add flags to your rake invocation for verbose output - that might help folks help you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was a MongoDB error. Data was not properly associated. After entering the console, and changed the document, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you run it dynamically?

```
heroku run rake twitter:start
```

Comment: Yes, but when you exit the Terminal, the rake task will end.