# Where exactly should I fetch tweets? (controllers, models, helpers, ...)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter

Although experienced with another frameworks, I'm a rails newbie. I've come upon [the main twitter gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/twitter) and want to use it. I understand the code... but I don't understand where exactly I should work it, at all (I've read plenty of *rails* but lack of practical examples).

1. I want to fetch the tweet info (post, user, etc)
2. Save the tweet to the database using postgre

   - I have a 'publication' (about the tweet) and 'publication' model, amongst helpers and so on.

Could someone please walk me through on how to do this? **I'm not asking for you to do my work. Just please explain me the thought process of rails via a lazy example** because I'm not understanding how to work with the gem this way... Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: your link is broken to the gem file, also its a good idea to name the gem name instead of naming it 'this'

Comment: None of the above - [Service Objects](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2014/04/30/gourmet-service-objects.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[max's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766372/where-exactly-should-i-fetch-tweets-controllers-models-helpers#comment51465064_31766372) is exactly right, but to help put it into context, let me illustrate how, in your situation, you can build and apply a service object.

First, consider what your service object will be doing, and pick a name for it (you'll often change this later, as you figure things out better). For example, `TweetFetcher`. Then, decide what information it needs before it can do its job. I'm not clear on which tweet(s) you want to fetch, from your question, but let's assume it just wants to fetch the latest tweet for a given handle. Then, your object can start out like so:

```
class TweetFetcher
  def initialize(handle)
    @handle = handle
  end
end
```

Now, this file can go anywhere Rails will automatically load it. The `lib/` folder is pretty standard (e.g. `lib/tweet_fetcher.rb`), but you may need to add `lib` to your autoload paths. Even simpler is to throw it into the `app/models` folder, though that's a bit confusing for future developers.

Next, make it do its job. You'll need to add a new method to your class which "calls" it; a standard name is `call` but you can pick what you'd like. At this point, I'd suggest you write tests for your service object, just like you would for a model, but I won't get into details on that. At the end of the process, your code will look like:

```
class TweetFetcher
  def initialize(handle)
    @handle = handle
  end

  def call
    # not real code at all
    tweet = Twitter::Client.fetch_latest_tweet(@handle)
    Publication.create!(tweet_id: tweet.id)
  end
end
```

Rock-solid. So, the next question is, when to call it? In general, I'd suggest calling service objects from your controllers. For example, say this is all supposed to happen when a user submits a form that they just entered a twitter handle into... say, `POST /publications`, which hits `PublicationsController#create`:

```
class PublicationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    # validate params, w/e
    @publication = TweetFetcher.new(params[:handle]).call
    flash[:notice] = "aaaand done."
  end
end
```

However, you could call your service object from anywhere -- that's the beauty of building them. It allows you to extract, encapsulate, and re-use code in any context. It also makes it way easier to test your code, as I think you'll find. Hope this helped, and good luck!

Comment: I think this definitely belongs somewhere in `app`. Either in `models` or a new folder called `processors` or something like that (I believe rails loads everything in `app` automatically).

Comment: I'd put in app/services as per https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services

Comment: Hello @robertnubel, thank you for your help.

Suppose I want to check for tweets using the API stream and parse them accordingly into an *Publication* after receiving them. Where exactly should I use TweetFetcher? welcome_controller.rb? application_controller.rb?

Comment: @Fane: You've told me *what* you want to do, but the key piece here is -- *when*? When a user fills out a form? Or just always, on a periodic schedule? If the latter, you'll need to use a task scheduling system like `cron` or [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler).

Comment: @RobertNubel neither. I want the *when* to be "constantly", using the twitter **stream** api. So there are no need for cron jobs at this stage. Whenever a topic "this-is-a-topic" is mentioned in tweeter, I get the tweet by stream and what I want to do is save it to the DB (postgre) using the *Publication* (name of the table is *Publication*s**). So basically, there must be a service constantly running  the background whenever I call "rails s" and let it run. Then get the tweet, parse it as I want and save it to the database...

Comment: Ah, so what you need is a separate, background Ruby process running a script for eternity (or until the server is shut down). This type of thing is generally called a [daemon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)), and this answer may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17666080/ruby-daemons-on-heroku. In short, it's not possible to have `rails s` spin up anything other than the web server, but you can use a tool like Foreman to start up your daemon and your server.

Comment: @RobertNubel are you absolutely sure? I don't mean to bother you with this but please check http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/twitter keyword 'stream'. it's a gem of rails, not pure ruby code only. I used a system similar in node.js and didn't need a daemon, only to run the stream code at the beginning of the node session... The problem with rails is that I don't understand where to put it :s

Comment: It's technically possible to have your Rails app fork off a new process that runs the streaming code, but that approach will fall apart when you deploy to production -- any Rails server in production using MRI Ruby runs multiple Rails processes per server, and with one Twitter-stream-fetcher per process, you'd get duplicates of every action or unexpected errors, etc. Even if you did just have one process per server, you'd eventually want to scale to multiple servers and hit the same problem.

Comment: Your approach in node.js worked because node.js is well-suited for running concurrent code (like your streaming logic), and because you were likely operating at a scale where you didn't need more than one process (or the concurrent code was perfectly fine running one-copy-per-process). You could get the same result from Rails, but it's just not as easy. And, like I mentioned above, it's not a production-ready answer. A daemon process can be independently monitored and maintained. Plus, you can boot it inside your Rails environment simply with: `rails runner -e production twitter_daemon.rb`.

Comment: @RobertNubel Ok, I got it :) thank you very much, you have been extremely helpful. I'll try your advices and let you know if something goes off ! Tyvm again :b